# No Genymotion device is able to produce audio

Tags: android, genymotion

Just formatted my mac and installed android studio along with Genymotion, Virtual box and the shell required. Now that I am working on a video player I found that not a single device is able to produce audio only video works. Can anyone please help me with this issue? Earlier( before formatting) it was working fine also I have already tried changing Host audio driver and Audio Controller from the Virtual Box for each device.

Comment: I think the last option will be to reinstall genymotion but first I want to know the issue.

Comment: This is possibly due to a bug on VirtualBox. Can you try with VBox 5.0?

Answer (score 0):

That's probably a known bug on VirtualBox. I advise you to test with VBox 5.0.28, the audio should be working well.